# WACOM Grip Pen nib lifetime

Tags: drawing-tablet

WACOM Intuos Pro is my first graphics tablet and in week or two nib become sharp, like pencil.
Also there is little scratches on tablet surface. I afraid there will be more of them and they will influence tablet's work. 
Is it normal nibs become sharp so fast, and little scratches appear so quickly? It was completely new tablet, and I'm just use it for hour or two every day.

Here is two nibs, each one after week of usage:

[image: nibs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *completely* depends upon the user - how often they use the tablet - how hard they press with the nib - the age of the tablet surface.

The new(er) tablet surfaces have a bit of a "tooth" to them. This does tend to chew through nibs much faster than the surfaces used to.

When I used an Intuos 2-4 the nib would last months, if not years. With the new "textured" surface of the Intuos 5 I found I was replacing nibs every month or so - but I use my tablet daily 100% of the time. I've never used an Intuos Pro. I have an Intuos 5 touch (which is basically the same as a "pro".) But I imagine the pro has the same textured surface as the 5 does.

Eventually the texture surface will get worn down to a smooth surface (similar to old Wacom surfaces) simply due to use. This tends to let the nib last much, much, much longer.

Wacom apparently changed the surfaces because users were commenting on not liking the glass-like smooth surface. I, personally, prefer the smooth, glass-like surface. With the Intuos 5, if you like the textured, nib-eating, surface it takes a *warranty repair* to replace the surface. This was a very non-consumer friendly decision by Wacom. It would probably be better to get used to the warn, smooth surface, than to send your tablet in for 10-20 days to get the surface replaced, and that's *if* it is still under warranty.

Nibs are relatively cheap, if you feel like the nib is scratching the tablet, it's time to replace it. How often you need to replace the nib is entirely dependent upon your use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've already tried to change nib to completely new, but even with this nib I scratched surface again. I'm not press it very much, but paint really fast, wide lines.

Comment: Are you *actually* causing gouges in the surface or does it simply *feel* like you're scratching it?

Comment: scott you sure it as not a solution based on need to sell more consumables

Comment: Scott, I don't feel scratching surface, I see pale little scratches after drawing.

Comment: The "paper like" textured surface is the worst. I've used plastic binders and ipad overlays on top of my bamboo to cover up that terrible texture. The ipad overlay has worked like magic, since it has it's own adhesive bottom surface. With such makeshift overlay, the pen nib can last years. Depending on the plastic thickness, it's very likely you won't be able to use touch gestures. --- My experience is that the stroke nib lasts the longest time.

Comment: @Joonas - I simply used mine so much the texture has [worn off leaving a glass-like surface](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3i0V0.jpg) :) Chewed through a few nibs to get there though.

Comment: When I think about the size of the nib... It should take years and a trashcan full of nibs to get it to that condition. Wacom really knows where to get the moneys... Bamboo was my first introduction to that texture. I used up 3 standard nibs in one weekend. 2 of the nibs were so worn that I had super hard time removing them.

Comment: Nah.. less than a year but daily use.

Comment: @Maria the textured surface will wear down as you use the tablet. This is Wacom's new model of surface - one which degrades down to smooth then requires a repair to replace. I'm not a fan of this, but it's how they work now.

Comment: Scott, thank you again for explanation! Your tablet's photo looks scary for me: so many scratches! But if it has no influence on tablet's work, I think I'll just continue to use my intuos pro without ipad overlays, paper or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Think I'm late to the party, but I think this could help others with the same issue:

After using my Wacom for only a week, the nib also ended up getting sharp -  probably because I hold my pen at an angle, so only a portion of the nib is actually touching the surface and is getting dull. The "untouched" part therefore gets sharp, I think.

Because I'm a cheapskate and don't like the idea of replacing nibs once a week, I resolved to turn the nibs every once in a while, making sure that the sharp edge is on the part that touches the tablet, so eventually the sharp part becomes dull as well. If the "untouched" part gets sharp, I turn it again.

So far, I've only had one scratch on the tablet and I'm gonna keep doing this until the nib becomes virtually invisible!